# Java: How to avoid AccessDeniedException when iterating though a files tree?

Tags: java, file, access-denied

with this piece of code I have been trying to look for specific codes in files within a tree of files.

```
List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
// logic to fill the list of codes ...
Path rootPath = Paths.get("C:\\some\\path");
Files.walk(rootPath).peek((path) -> {
    for(String code : codes) {
        try {
            Files.lines(path).filter((line) -> line.contains(code)).peek((line) -> {
                System.out.println(path.toString() + " -> " + code);
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).count();
```

But when I run it, I am only getting a whole lot of `AccessDeniedException`s.
Though the files are not open currently by other programs, and `Files.isWritable(path)` as well as `Files.isReadable(path)` both return true for all the files.

So how can I improve my program or how can I change the file properties in windows to make this work?

Thanks and Greetings,
Daniel

Comment: Check by placing the file in other drives other than c

Comment: Are you asking how to read the lines from a file you don't have permission to read from?